# read time from linux and set it to arduino RTC

Tags: timer, arduino, serial-port, real-time-clock

I write script from openwrt to send "0" to arduino via usb serial port if arduino receive that character it will be trigger  pin 8 to LOW

But my problem is right now is i have RTCds1307 when linux openwrt connected to NTP it provide time to set to arduino RTC via usb shell script for this job will run and the data sent over serial it contain 0  number that trigger command that i said above

So here my question

Is there anyway to send time data over usb without interrupt another PIN 8 low command

Comment: Just to be clear: when your script sends a new time for RTC, any `'0'` character in it triggers setting `pin8` to `LOW`?

Comment: @kiiv  that's right.